# How to fetch UTC dates with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, utc

I want to get the current UTC date with Javascript. How can I do this? There seems to be methods for getting the time in UTC:

```
date.getUTCHours();
```

How can I get the *date*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are UTC getters for [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate), [day](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDay), [full year](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCFullYear), [hour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours), [minutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMinutes), [month](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth), [etc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date). To get the date specifically, you might find [getUTCDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate) useful.

Without seeing more of your code, I can only suggest this:

```
date.getUTCDate();
```